# Send XML via HTTP post request via Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Hello Everybody I am trying to send XML as parameter by HTTP request,but cause of
`dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)` my request  string was failure.
Here is my code:

```
    let xmlRequest = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<response operation="getAccounts" handler="aphena">
    <Id>11536502</Id>
    <getAccountsParameters>
        <client>654</client>
    </getAccountsParameters>
</response>"
    let requestXmlData = xmlRequest.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let url = NSURL(string:"http://115.70.40.118:5800/mobile_bank/api")!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = requestXmlData!
```

In server I got this cod:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n<response operation=\"getAccounts\" handler=\"aphena\">\n\t<Id>11536502</Id>\n\t<getAccountsParameters>\n\t\t<client>654</client>\n\t</getAccountsParameters>\n</response>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried `alamofire`

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: Thanks,Yes I've already tried,but there you can send parameters as json.I need send as String without any NSUTF8StringEncoding

Comment: What exactly is your failure? What is your problem?

Comment: I don't want to encode my special characters for example enter,tab,"\"

Comment: isn't what the server received a correct xml?

Comment: I have received correct XML,only I could not send correct XML to the server.In above there is my request XML to the server

Comment: Thank you for all answers,I solved my problem.The reason of incorrect xml has been from server.

Comment: Hi, you can talk detail about your error reason because I have get a same problem and I have not still solved it. Thanks